# Очистка истории браузера на selenium webdriver > c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Нужно очистить историю в Visual Studio (на selenium driver). Язык использовал C#. Пытался очистить браузер методом поиска элементов (FindElement) и кликами , но на странице (chrome://history/), код словно не видит ,и выдает ошибку(no such element: Unable to locate element: ), при этом страница была открыта и элемент должен был быть найден. 
..

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://history/");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("clear-browsing-data")).Click();
```

Если вы знаете более легкий способ очистки истории браузера или решение этого, то черкните.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

вроде так:

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```